# Observing @State var changes from UIViewRepresentable in SwiftUI View

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

I have the following Swift view:

```
struct GameView: View {
    @State private var userWon: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            print("userWon: \(userWon)") // not called
            // TODO: Change game state here
        }
    }
    
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            GameViewRepresentable(userWon: $userWon)
                .onChange(of: userWon) { newValue in
                    print("GameViewRepresentable: \(newValue)") // called
                    // TODO: or change game state here?
                }
        }
        .clipped()
    }
   }
}
```

The view representable is like so:

```
struct GameViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = GameView
    @Binding var userWon: Bool {
        willSet { newValue
            print("willSet userWon: \(newValue)")
        }
        didSet {
            print("didSet userWon: \(userWon)")
        }
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> GameView {
        let gameView = GameView()
        gameView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return gameView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: GameView, context: Context) {
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> GameViewCoordinator {
        GameViewCoordinator(self)
    }

    class GameViewCoordinator: GameViewDelegate  {
        var parent: GameViewRepresentable
        
        init(_ parent: GameViewRepresentable) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func userWon() {
            self.parent.userWon = true
        }
    }
}
```

I can see that the `userWon` method is correctly getting called inside the coordinator which correspondingly calls `willSet` and `didSet` in `GameViewRepresentable`, but the `didSet` in the `GameView` for the binding `userWon` property is never called. However the `onChange` in GameView does get called. So is that the right way to respond to changes to the state property? I was expecting the `didSet` inside the GameView to get called instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `onChange` is how you detect `@State` changes.

It is perfectly normal for `willSet` and `didSet` to not be triggered on a `@State` or `@Binding`. Swift inserts calls to `willSet` and `didSet` in the setter of the `userWon` property, so if `userWon` changes *not* by calling `userWon`'s setter, then `willSet` and `didSet` will not be called.

Your `userWon` property lowers to something like this:

```
private var _userWon = State(initialValue: false)
private var userWon: Bool {
    get { _userWon.wrappedValue }
    set { 
        // <willSet is called here>
        _userWon.wrappedValue = newValue 
        // <didSet is called here>
    }
}
private var $userWon: Binding<Bool> {
    _userWon.projectedValue
}
```

Consider this really simple example:

```
@State private var userWon: Bool = false {
    willSet {
        print("willSet")
    }
    didSet {
        print("didSet")
    }
}

var body: some View {
    Toggle(isOn: $userWon) {
        Text("Foo")
    }
}
```

No matter how many times I toggle the toggle, `willSet` and `didSet` are not called. This is because the `Toggle` doesn't actually change the value of `userWon` by literally saying e.g. `userWon = true` (which would have called its setter). `Toggle` doesn't know that `userWon` exists at all.

What actually happens is you passed a `Binding<Bool>` to the `Toggle`, which was the `projectedValue` of the `State`. `$userWon` is just a short way of saying `_userWon.projectedValue`. The `Toggle` will at some point set the `wrappedValue` property of the `Binding<Bool>`. This will then cause the `wrappedValue` of the `State` to be set, and the view gets updated.

Notice that everything is done through the `wrappedValue` properties of `State` and `Binding`, not your `userWon` property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `updateUIView`, e.g.

```
   func updateUIView(_ uiView: GameView, context: Context) {
        context.coordinator.parent = self 
    }
```

Note, it would be better practice to set new closures on the coordinator instead.

Comment: Unless Apple has it wrong I don’t think it is a mistake https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit

Comment: it's a mistake, sometimes those tutorials are written by interns

Comment: Fruta PaymentButton has done in a different way that also works

Comment: It is just a style choice like many other things, I’ve said  it before my only issue with some of your posts is the absoluteness of your choice of words.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/10075

Comment: Ok I updated the code to what’s shown in the video at 18:21