# How to observe multiple changes in UIViewRepresentable?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, uiviewrepresentable

Continuing from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77065712/observing-state-var-changes-from-uiviewrepresentable-in-swiftui-view), what is the best way to observe several state changes from a `UIViewRepresentable`? Previously, I required to only observe changes to one property `userWon`. However, as new functionality was introduced in the app, I need to now observe new changes. Assuming these could increase even more, is the best way to do this by adding more `State` properties and binding them to the `UIViewRepresentable`? It feels somewhat hacky at this point to add more and more bindings and `onChange` modifiers to observe for changes.
Example code is as follows:

```
struct GameView: View {
    @State private var userWon: Bool = false
    @State private var propA: Bool = false
    @State private var propB: Int = 0
    @State private var propC: Int = 0
    ...
    ...
    ...
    @State private var propZ: Int = 0
    @StateObject private var gameService = GameService()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                GameViewRepresentable(userWon: $userWon,
                                      propA: $propA,
                                      propB: $propB,
                                      propC: $propC,
                                      ...
                                      propZ: $propZ) // <- Add more bindings??
                    .onChange(of: userWon) { newValue in
                        if newValue {
                           gameService.updateUserScore()
                        }
                    }
                    .onChange(of: propA) { newValue in
                           gameService.doSomethingA()
                    }
                    .onChange(of: propB) { newValue in
                           gameService.doSomethingB()
                    }
                    .onChange(of: propZ) { newValue in
                           gameService.doSomethingZ()
                    }
            }
            .clipped()
        }
    }
}

struct GameViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = GameView
    @Binding var userWon: Bool
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> GameView {
        let gameView = GameView()
        gameView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return gameView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: GameView, context: Context) {
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> GameViewCoordinator {
        GameViewCoordinator(self)
    }

    class GameViewCoordinator: GameViewDelegate  {
        var parent: GameViewRepresentable
        
        init(_ parent: GameViewRepresentable) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func userWon() {
            self.parent.userWon = true
        }
    }
}
```

Alternate approach that I can think of is:

1. Create an envelope object/model in `gameService` that contains the aforementioned properties to be observed and pass that as binding to the `UIViewRepresentable`.
2. Have `gameService` observe this enveloped object, probably using `Combine`? for changes but I'm not sure how to do this or if it'd work at all.
   Any help is appreciated on how to do this efficiently.

Comment: Your first alternate approach looks fine to me. What's the problem with it?

Comment: You don't actually need to make an "envelope object". Just move all these properties into `GameViewModel` as `@Published var`s.

Comment: It didn't feel right in the sense that although I'd be creating the wrapper object in the view model and pass it as a binding to the view representable, I'd still be observing changes using `onChange` in the view.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to also de-clutter the implementation by having the properties and its observing mechanism in the same object to say so. Is it possible to combine approaches 1 & 2? i.e. have the properties as Published vars in the view model and observe them using combine? I've never done this before so I don't know if updating the bindings of the properties in the view representable would cause observable changes for the view model to take action on.

Comment: Yes it is possible to combine 1 and 2, but I feel like the root of the problem is the giant black box that is `GameViewRepresentable`. If you could split it up into multiple SwiftUI views that has their own state, you wouldn't need so many `@State` in the parent. The views can then interact with the game model through an `@EnvironmentObject` or similar.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out. And I agree with you about the ViewRepresentable. Unfortunately the view it wraps is a custom `UIView` written ages ago that does a ton of stuff and updating it is off limits due to various reasons.

Comment: you still need to remove the view model object and implement updateUIView to set the new parent on the coordinator. Just define new let properties on your representable. update will be called when they change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move all the `@State var`s into your `GameService` as `@Published var`s.

```
class GameService: ObservableObject {
    @Published var someGameState = 1
    @Published var anotherGameState = 1

    func doSomething() {
        print(someGameState)
    }
    func doSomethingElse() {
        print(anotherGameState)
    }
}
```

Then you can pass this to `GameViewRepresentable` through an `@ObservedObject`, to avoid writing out all the states the game view needs.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var game = GameService()
    
    var body: some View {
        GameViewRepresentable(game: game)
    }
}

struct GameViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var game: GameService
    
    // ...
}
```

Since this is a `UIViewRepresentable`, I think you would likely be updating `game` through its properties' setters (rather than say, a `Binding` produced from the projected value of `ObservedObject`). In that case, you can just use `didSet` to detect the changes:

```
@Published var someGameState = 1 {
    didSet { self.doSomething() }
}
@Published var anotherGameState = 1 {
    didSet { self.doSomethingElse() }
}
```

Otherwise, changes can be detected using `onReceive`:

```
// add .dropFirst() if you don't want the initial value to trigger this
.onReceive(game.$someGameState) { _ in
    game.doSomething()
}
.onReceive(game.$anotherGameState) { _ in
    game.doSomethingElse()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with moving the properties to the view model and using their setters to keep extra code from being added to the view.

Comment: This is SwiftUI so the View struct plus state already is a view model. `@StateObject` is designed for something else.

Comment: @malhal I know that. This seems to be a common misunderstanding of SwiftUI. But this question isn’t about that. We know very little about what `GameViewModel` does. For all I know, it could just be OP’s data (e.g. the current game state), but OP incorrectly calls it a “view model”, because everyone else is doing it. I’m not going to assume that it is what it says.

Comment: @malhal If you just don't like the word `ViewModel` in my code, I've removed it.

Comment: @malhal could you elaborate more? I came across this extract which presumably was taken from an ask Apple event [on a question about MVVM](https://fatbobman.medium.com/ask-apple-2022-q-a-related-to-swiftui-part-1-cf3368a66e32): `In short, we do not recommend using the view as the viewModel. However, SwiftUI does provide tools to implement the classic MVVM architecture (such as StateObjects, ObservedObjects). ` It seems to me like its a problem of nomenclature than substance tbh. Like in my case my `GameViewModel` actually is a game service of sorts and doesn't do any view data preparation.

Comment: @batman Yeah, I thought it is a problem of nomenclature too, hence my reply to malhal. That said, if it isn't actually a view model, it's better if you edit your question to rename the type, to avoid further confusions.

Comment: Yup, I agree. It's a bad habit I've been trying to break since I'm fairly new to SwiftUI so I've sort of carried over the naming conventions from just Swift programming. I've renamed it to `GameService` for the sake of this question.

Comment: [Another link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fThwWm-Tv7c&t=213s) that also document's the Apple dev's response that I linked to earlier. I've watched quite a few wwdc videos & I've always got the feeling that while the model's in the sample code presented aren't named as `viewmodel`, they still somewhat behave like them even if they are called Store, Service, Manager or something else. I felt this strongly from a data flow video on SwiftUI in wwdc 20 i think? Might be irrelevant to the question but I'd love to get viewpoints on this for a definitive understanding on this subject.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255434/discussion-between-batman-and-sweeper).

Comment: @batman yes you could try to re-implement SwiftUI's architecture in MVVM using StateObjects but that is a complete waste of time, you'll eventually get stuck when you want to use async/await, so it's better to just use SwiftUI as its designed, i.e. use the View struct hierarchy and state/binding.